# Microsoft Access If statement Query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to figure out why my below query is not working.

I have created a calculated field and as part of an `IIf()` I am looking at doing a `LEFT` function.

I am hoping to return the First char of the Display Value of a column rather than the Hidden Primary Key.

Just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Could you define is not working? Does it produce a wrong result, or does it show a #N/A error

Answer (score 2):

You can debug this yourself by doing a couple of things.  You haven't really provided specific information to what the problem you're facing.

First I would rewrite the query as such to reduce the number of paranthesis and make the intention/logic much clearer, which will also make it easier to debug.

```
IIf([General Notes] In ("FFA", "Consignment", "CCO", "Hargreaves", "SCRAP"), [General Notes], Left([Supplier_ID],1))
```

Then start with the following step and identify which field is causing the problem by breaking the query into seperate fields

```
IIf([General Notes] In ("FFA", "Consignment", "CCO", "Hargreaves", "SCRAP"), [General Notes], "") 
Left([Supplier_ID],1)
etc
```

As for the display value of the column rather than the hidden primary key, `[Supplier_ID]` sounds awfully like a name that would be given to a key.  Perhaps you mean to place something like `[Supplier_Name]` or `[Supplier]` etc.

Comment: Great hint about the IIF and In - I wasn't aware of that!

Comment: @ashareef,  many thanks I will look at making the query more efficient as discussed above and make a start on debugging.